# ArgoCD Manifest generation error (cached): the URL scheme 'secrets' is not allowed error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

When updating from 3.31.1 ArgoCD to 3.33.5 I got this error: ComparisonError - ArgoCD Manifest generation error (cached): the URL scheme 'secrets' is not allowed error

Is there any fix?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional as there was a CVE specific to this (cant remember specific CVE or which release mitigated it). If you are trying to use a helm custom scheme, you can allow a different scheme by modifying the `argocd-cm` configmap

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/operator-manual/argocd-cm.yaml#L230

Comment: So I need to modify this? helm.valuesFileSchemes: http, https? Is there a new version of argo that can fix that?

Comment: its not a "fix", its a configuration now and its disabled by default for security reasons